# Roomle Blender Addon is required to prepare models for loading as external meshes

Tags: roomle

We are trying to add external mesh to configurable product. As stated in documentation we need the Blender plugin which is provided by Roomle.
https://docs.roomle.com/blender-addon/#download

Can someone provide a download link?

Comment: Found it here if someone needs it https://gitlab.com/roomle/tools/roomle-blender-addon/-/tree/master. This should probably be stated in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the link to the development repository for Roomle Blender Addon: https://gitlab.com/roomle/tools/roomle-blender-addon

And direct download link for the build in version 2.1.0: https://docs.roomle.com/scripting/resources/plugins/roomle_blender_addon_2.1.0.zip